# pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have installed pyodbc, unixodbc inside the container but I am getting the below error while running the container. Can anyone help me to fix this.

```
Recreating NewAPIPlatform001 ... done
Attaching to cross_sell_h2l_NewAPIPlatform001
NewAPIPlatform001  | 2019-11-02 10:58:14,382 — INFO — __main__ -    run_API.py:24 -             <module>() — Locating environment variables.
NewAPIPlatform001  | 2019-11-02 10:58:14,384 — INFO — __main__ - run_API.py:54 -             <module>() — Getting data between 201910 and 201910.
NewAPIPlatform001  | Traceback (most recent call last):
NewAPIPlatform001  |   File "run_API.py", line 61, in <module>
NewAPIPlatform001  |     df = data.get_data(min_month=args['min_month'],     max_month=args['max_month'])
NewAPIPlatform001  |   File "/usr/src/NewAPIPlatform001/src/data/data.py", line 116, in get_data
NewAPIPlatform001  |     conn = get_conn(database='CENTRAL_MART', choice='ware')
NewAPIPlatform001  |   File "/usr/src/NewAPIPlatform001/src/data/data.py", line 61, in get_conn
NewAPIPlatform001  |     pwd=os.environ.get('WARE_PWD'),
NewAPIPlatform001  | pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver  Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
NewAPIPlatform001 exited with code 1


My Docker-compose file looks like below:

FROM python:3.6
COPY . /usr/src/NewAPIPlatform001
WORKDIR /usr/src/NewAPIPlatform001
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install unixodbc-dev -y bash
RUN apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 unixodbc
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: can you please add some markup. the code is difficult to read.

Comment: Can you please have a look and let me know pls